# Binding to a Service from a GCMListenerService

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an IM app consisting of
8 Activities
1 Service - bound service forming core app functionality
1 AppGcmListenerService

When a GCM push message is received, I need to bind/launch the Service (if it has been killed by the OS), and pass the message on to process. My understanding is that the GcmListenerService will be killed once it exits onMessageReceived, so I don't think asynchronously binding to the Service is an option (GcmListenerService may be killed before service has successfully bound).

I can't use a LocalBroadcastManager, as the Service may have been killed by the OS (needs to be woken by being bound to).

I can't convert my service to inherit from GcmListenerService, as this class is not designed to be extended in this way (onStartCommand is marked final).

Any ideas as to how I could tackle this problem?

Comment: what about `startService` ? dont you want to start a sevice?

Comment: Thanks for answering such a dumb question, @pskink

Comment: @Dave is it working? are you able to start the service and how did you get the reference of context to start the service. I have tried to start the service using BaseContext and ApplicationContext but didnt work.